# Website login not remembered in multiple UIWebViews

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm creating a Hybrid iPhone App that contains a lot of separate UIWebViews that point to specific pages on a website. These pages are secured, so I show a page with a standard .NET login form first. This login succeeds.

However, if I load the subsequent pages in other webviews it still redirects me to the login page. I requested all the cookies that are set for the URL and it contains a .NET session ID and everything. Is there some other reason that these kind of sessions wouldn't be shared between UIWebViews?

Comment: Is it possible that this site intentionally won't remember previous sessions?

Comment: I'm 99% sure it's not an issue with the site itself. I tried this scenario with my normal desktop-browser with multiple tabs and multiple windows, in all these cases the session was remembered.

Answer (score 0):

Can you control the server side?  I suspect that new instances of Safari are triggering new server sessions, perhaps you need to create some kind of recover session function and call it via a web service for each UIWebView.